# I Try to run angular project 'ng serve' after that i get the error the while bundling the DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser')

Tags: angularjs

- Generating browser application bundles...(node:14340) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
  (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
  \ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...C:\Users\somna\OneDrive\Desktop\devlopment\teaching\udemy\services-assignment-solution\services-assignment-solution\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:106
  throw new Error("callback(): The callback was already called.");

I try to install node package using --legacy-peer-deps also.